# How to create a Login modal dialog using jQuery mobile with $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use jquery mobile dialogs to create a login form.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and jquery mobile 1.0.  We've decided to disable ajax transitions site wide for various reasons which may or may not be salient to my question.  The following post got me part of the way there:

[jquery mobile dialog with ajaxenabled=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649428/jquery-mobile-dialog-with-ajaxenabled-false)

I'm able to programmatically open a login dialog using the method described but I still have two rather significant obstacles.
1) The login dialog needs to post back to the server for validation, etc.  Once I hit submit, the controller validateds, and then rerenders the view with validation errors, but the page is no longer in 'dialog' mode, it ends up just returning as a regular page view.
2) The login link is available on every page of the site, but the login itself needs to be secure/ssl.  jquery mobile doesn't seem to like the transition from http to https when loading the login page.

Does anyone have any good examples of how to create a secure jquery mobile dialog form with postback validation, or point me to a site that they've seen that might already be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1) When you render the errors, render a page that looks like a modal is opened on it.  You can just do this in CSS.
2) I think you just need the action of the form you're posting to be https, not the page that gets rendered if there's a login error (just don't render the password).  If that has problems, set up a little example page we can navigate to and check it out.